# Как добавить события в PropertyGrid для компонента Windows Forms Designer?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я сделал конструктор форм Windows Forms с помощью DesignSurface, связал его с PropertyGrid, но не могу добавить туда раздел с событиями аналогично VisualStudio. Пришлите, пожалуйста, ссылки на CodeProject/github по реализации этой задачи.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dc85a892-5cec-41ae-8b83-e16451675e54/propertygrid-adding-eventstab?forum=winformsdesigner), вроде, то, что вам нужно. Но сложно, да.

Comment: Спасибо, при работе с возможностями дизайнера форм было гораздо сложнее)

Comment: Не подскажете, какой тип коллекции должен быть возвращен при помощи GetCompatibleMethods?